# Can't fix it: signInWithGoogle isn't defined for the class 'Firebase auth'

Tags: dart

The method 'signInWithGoogle' isn't defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'.

I have tried to change versions of pubspec.yaml file but it is not working because the firebase auth,google_sign_in,firebase analytics, firebase database are of different versions. 
I had changed dependencies in build gradle file but it didn't help me out also.
Either i can't find my keytool according to google to acquire SHA-1 fingerprint for firebase google authentication.

```
    final googleSignIn = new GoogleSignIn();
    final analytics = new FirebaseAnalytics();
    final auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final reference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Blogs');
    String temp;
    enum _DesignAppMenuItems { profile, logout }

    class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    HomePageState createState() => new HomePageState();
    }

    class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
    bool loggedIn = false;
    bool _googleLoginProgress = false;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    Future<Null> _function() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    this.setState(() {
    if (prefs.getString("username") != null) {
     loggedIn = true;
      } else {
        loggedIn = false;
      }
     });
     }

     Future<Null> checkStatusOfUser() async {
     await _ensureLoggedIn();
     }

     Future<Null> _ensureLoggedIn() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs;
      prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;

      try {
      if (user == null) user = await googleSignIn.signInSilently();
      if (user == null) {
        user = await googleSignIn.signIn();
        analytics.logLogin();
      }
      if (await auth.currentUser() == null) {
        GoogleSignInAuthentication credentials =
            await googleSignIn.currentUser.authentication;

        await auth.signInWithGoogle(
          idToken: credentials.idToken,
          accessToken: credentials.accessToken,
        );
      }
      prefs.setString("username", user.displayName);
      prefs.setString("userid", user.id);
      prefs.setString("useremail", user.email);
      prefs.setString("userphotourl", user.photoUrl);
      analytics.logLogin();
      final userRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('Users');
      userRef
          .child(user.id)
          .set({"name": user.displayName, "image": user.photoUrl});
      this.setState(() {
        loggedIn = true;
        _googleLoginProgress = false;
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
....
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Scaffold.....
```

Compiler message:

> lib/HomePage.dart:63:20: Error: The method 'signInWithGoogle' isn't
>   defined for the class 'FirebaseAuth'.
>    - 'FirebaseAuth' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'signInWithGoogle'.
>           await auth.signInWithGoogle(
>                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lib/PostBlogPage.dart:30:16: Error: The method 'signInWithGoogle' isn't defined for the class
>   'FirebaseAuth'.
>    - 'FirebaseAuth' is from 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' ('file:///C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_auth-0.7.0/lib/firebase_auth.dart').
>   Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining
>   a method named 'signInWithGoogle'.
>       await auth.signInWithGoogle(
>                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Compiler failed on C:\Users\Ankit\AndroidStudioProjects\blogand\lib\main.dart Finished
>   with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

You need to use signInWithCredential instead of signInWithGoogle.

Link Here: https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/firebase_auth

Add the following imports to your Dart code:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
```

Initialize GoogleSignIn and FirebaseAuth:

```
final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
```

You can now use the Firebase _auth to authenticate in your Dart code, e.g.

```
Future<FirebaseUser> _handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );

  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  return user;
}
```

Then from the sign in button onPress, call the _handleSignIn method using a future callback for both the FirebaseUser and possible exception.

```
_handleSignIn()
    .then((FirebaseUser user) => print(user))
    .catchError((e) => print(e));
```

Comment: according to my code, it can't be replaced by this code because as per my code another variables are disturbed. Can you provide a pubspec.yaml file according to the use of firebase (firebase auth,firebase database etc).

Comment: I have the following dependencies:cloud_firestore: ^0.7.4
  shared_preferences: "^0.4.0"
  firebase_auth: 0.7.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.0.2
  firebase_analytics: "^0.3.0"
  image_picker: "^0.4.1"
  firebase_database: "^0.4.2"
  firebase_storage: "^0.2.0"
  transparent_image: "^0.1.0"

Comment: Why haven't you updated these packages? Firebase_auth is currently on version 0.11.1+7. Firebase_analytics on 3.0.3, image_picker on 0.6.0+10. If I were you I'd go in and search your packages on https://pub.flutter-io.cn/ and update to the most current version possible.

Comment: As you said i have updated my packages but nothing will happen.

Comment: What did you mean in your first comment "other variables are disturbed"?